# Can't find the error message in x32dbg

Tags: x64dbg

Am trying to reverse an activation program using the error message in reference string
[image]

but searching for the string is not successful "all modules - string reference"
[image]
tried to pause after reaching the error and adding breakpoint through handles but no luck yet

Comment: It could be a resource string, loaded with e.g. `LoadString`, a good starting point might be to open the binary with a tool like Resource Hacker.

Comment: Or the string could be obfuscated